# Query on plotting Lorenz curves on Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to plot a lorenz curve, using the following command:

```
glcurve drugs, sortvar(death) pvar(rank) glvar(yord) lorenz nograph

generate rank1=rank
label variable rank "Cum share of mortality"
label variable rank1 "Equality Line"

twoway (line rank1 rank, sort clwidth(medthin) clpat(longdash))(line yord rank , sort clwidth(medthin) clpat(red)), ///
ytitle(Cumulative share of drug activity, size(medsmall)) yscale(titlegap(2)) xtitle(Cumulative share of mortality (2012), size(medsmall)) ///
legend(rows(5)) xscale(titlegap(5)) legend(region(lwidth(none))) plotregion(margin(zero)) ysize(6.75) xsize(6) plotregion(lcolor(none))
```

However, in the resultant curves, the Line of equality does not start from 0, is there a way to fix this?

Is it recommended to use the following in order to get the perfect 45 degree line of equality:

```
(function y=x, range(0 1)
```

Also, how many minimum observations are required to plot the above graph? Does it work well with 2 observations as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your Line of Perfect Equality does not pass through (0,0) is because the values for your variable do not contain 0.

The smallest  value you will have for rank will be `1/_N`. Although this value will asymptotically approach 0, it will never actually reach 0.

To see this, try:

```
quietly sum rank
di r(min)
di 1/_N
```

Further, by applying the program code to your data (beginning around line 152 in the ado file and removing unnecessary bits), one can easily see that yord cannot take on a value of 0 without values of 0 for drugs:

```
glcurve drugs, sortvar(death) pvar(rank) glvar(yord) lorenz nograph

sort death drugs , stable 
gen double rank1 = _n / _N
qui sum drugs
gen yord1= (sum(drugs) / _N) / r(mean)
```

The best way to plot your Equality would be the method from your edit, namely:

`twoway(function y = x, ra(0 1))`

One quick yet (very) crude fix to force the lorenz curve to start at the origin (if it doesn't already) is to add an observation to the data after obtaining rank and yord, and then deleting it after you have your curve:

```
glcurve drugs, sortvar(death) pvar(rank) glvar(yord) lorenz nograph
expand 2 in 1
replace yord = 0 in 1
replace rank = 0 in 1

twoway (function y = x, ra(0 1)) ///
(line yord rank)
drop in 1
```

Like I said, this is admittedly crude and even somewhat ill advised, but I can't see a much better alternative at the moment, and with this method you will not be altering any of the other values of yord by running `glcurve` on the extrapolated data.